# Type inference fails horribly when omitting argument label on a function call

Tags: label, parameter-passing, ocaml, type-inference

Given the following function

```
let get_or ~default =
  function | Some a -> a
           | None -> default
```

If this function is called with the argument labeled, it works as expected:

```
let works = get_or ~default:4 (Some 2)
```

But if the label is omitted it somehow fails:

```
let fails = get_or 4 (Some 2)
```

It gets weirder, however, the error message given here by the compiler is:

> This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type ('a -> 'b) option

Not only has the compiler incorrectly inferred it to be an option, but for some reason it also pulls a function type out of the proverbial magician's hat! So naturally I wonder: where on earth does that come from? And somewhat less immediately important to my curiosity, why doesn't omitting the label work in this specific case?

See [this reason playground](https://reasonml.github.io/try/?ocaml=DYUwLgBA5uD6D2AnCA-AJiAZgQwK7EgF4AoCCTXAOwGMwBLeSiAHwgGV4BbECbCAWgB8vYgEhRZFhAByjHkIgYc+MMWKhIAdyQBrAM4RC0OElRK8BAFwAWCAAoO3CACYAlOvDlsdYAaMwwBGRbBy4eNyA) for an interactive example.

Credit for this puzzle goes to @nachotoday on the [Reason Discord](https://discord.gg/reasonml).

Comment: Optional labelled parameter actually *do* have an `option` type

Comment: @Bergi It isn't optional though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case of destructive interference between labelled arguments, currying and first class functions. The function `get_or` has for type

```
 val get_or: default:'a -> 'a option -> 'a
```

The rule with labelled arguments is that labels can be omitted when the application is total. At first glance, this means that if one apply `get_or` to two arguments, then it is a total application. But the fact that the return type of `get_or` is polymorphic (aka `'a`) spells trouble. Consider for instance:

```
let id x = x
let x : _ -> _ = get_or (Some id) id ~default:id
```

This is valid code, where `get_or` was applied to three arguments and where the default argument was provided at the third position!

Going even further, as surprising at it might see, this is still valid:

```
let y : default:_ -> _ -> - = get_or (Some id) id id
```

And it yields a quite complicated type for `y`.

The generic rule here is that if the return type of a function is polymorphic then the type-checker can never know if a function application is total or not; and thus labels can never be ommited.

Going back to your example, this means that the type-checker reads

```
 get_or (4) (Some 2)
```

as

- First, `get_or` has for type `default:'a -> 'a option -> 'a`.
  The default label has not been provided yet,
  so the result will have for type `default:'r -> 'r`
- Looking at `r`, in `get_or 2 (Some 4)`, `get_or` has for type
  `'a option -> 'a`, thus `get_or x:'a`
- Then `get_or x:'a` is applied to `y`; thus `'a = 'b -> 'c`
- In other words, I should have `x: ('b -> ' c) option`
  but I know that `x:int`.

Which leads to the contradiction reported by the type-checker, `2` was expected to be a function option `('a -> 'b) option`, but was obviously a int.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I don't quite understand the details of the inference process, what you mean by "for type" and what `get_or x` really refers to, but I think I understand _why_ it happens at least :)

Comment: rephrasing the type inference : as we don't have total application (because of polymorphism), the search for the "labeled" part is deferred, and we can assume the type of `get_or` is `'a option -> 'a`. since we apply the result to a value we have that `'a = 'b->'c`, and the compiler check that the argument `2 : int` is of type `('b->'c) option` which fails.